# Embed chromium extensions in the build itself

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium

I am creating a chromium clone, how do I embed (preferably unremovable) apps and extensions in the build process itself

Comment: Since the probability of someone answering this is pretty low, I think you can start by analyzing Chromium's code in IDE or [online](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch).

Comment: It is a pretty broad question and also the way it's asked could make people think you're looking to do something possibly malicious... Maybe you should do as wOxxOm said and examine the code, then ask questions that are a bit more specific and in context.  Just a piece of advice.

Comment: Seems like a good question to me, I have same question. Should probably have asked on the chromium-dev list for better answers.